# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'icon' of null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, material-ui

i have a form for editing the tab. When a edit icon is clicked to edit that tab a form in dialog box appears where the input box has current data in it. But when i hit save without touching the icon field i get an error of **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'icon' of null.** If i did not touch the name field and only touch on icon field and hit save button then the tab gets edited. How can i make icon field work too like name field is working ? I mean if i want to only edit name, i can edit the name from name field and save without touching icon field which will save the tab name with edited name and current icon.

How can it be possible?

[image]

```
class EditForm extends Component {
  render() {
    const { tab } = this.props;
    console.log('tab object is', this.props.tab);
    const listOfIcon = _.map(this.props.fetchIcon.icons, (singleIcon) => ({
                              text: singleIcon.name,
                              id: singleIcon.id,
                              value: <MenuItem primaryText={singleIcon.name} />

                        }));
    return (
      <div>
      <form
        onSubmit={(e) => {
                            console.log('auto', e.target.auto);
                            e.preventDefault();
                            this.props.editTab(
                                        tab.id,
                                        e.target.text.value,
                                        this.state.icon
                                    );
                            this.props.closeTabIcon();
                        }
        }
      >
        <div className="tab-name">
          <TextField
            hintText={tab.name}
            name="text"
            defaultValue={tab.name}
            hintStyle={{ display: 'none' }}
            floatingLabelStyle={{ color: '#1ab394' }}
            floatingLabelFocusStyle={{ color: '#1db4c2' }}
            underlineStyle={{ borderColor: '#1ab394' }}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="icon">
          <AutoComplete
            floatingLabelText={tab.icon}
            name="auto"
            filter={AutoComplete.noFilter}
            openOnFocus
            dataSource={listOfIcon}
            textFieldStyle={{ borderColor: '#1ab394' }}
            className="autocomplete"
            onNewRequest={(e) => { this.setState({ icon: e.id }); }}
          />
        </div>
        <button className="btn">Save</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    console.log(state);
    return {
        fetchIcon: state.fetchIcon,
        tabs: state.tabs.tabs.map(tab => {
            const icons = state.fetchIcon.icons.find(icon => Number(icon.id) === tab.icon);
            return {
                ...tab,
                icon: icons && icons.name
            };
        })
    };
};

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({
    editTab,
    closeTabIcon
  }, dispatch);
}
```

Comment: where, what line is the error?

Comment: The error is on this.state.icon . I could not pass value of icon like i have passed for name. Because i need to pass id of icon not the name.

Comment: You haven't defined state, and in redux icon will be passed a a prop. this could be the problem

Comment: how can it be done? If i select the icon from input field then it will work but there is a case when user need not even touch the icon if they don't want to update the icon.

Answer (score 0):

The state of a componnet is intitated with the null. YOu can set the intital value of state in constrocutor of the class

```
    class EditForm extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
       super(props)
       this.state ={}
      }
      render() {
        const { tab } = this.props;
        console.log('tab object is', this.props.tab);
        const listOfIcon = _.map(this.props.fetchIcon.icons, (singleIcon) => ({
                                  text: singleIcon.name,
                                  id: singleIcon.id,
                                  value: <MenuItem primaryText={singleIcon.name} />

                            }));..........
```

Comment: I want the current icon value to be filled in the input box so i should pass the props inside state object or what? I mean like if my tab name is dashboard with dashboard icon then when clicking the edit for that tab a form with name field containing the name dashboard and icon field with dashboard icon should be shown.

Comment: @Learner where is the value of the icon? in props or in state

Comment: in props fetchIcon. You can see in listOfIcon object

Comment: then why are using state to access the icon, why don't use props?

Comment: I can use props to access but how can i update icon when user edit.

Comment: that depends on your app, what you can do for now is , assign the props to state and access the icon info from state and when update happens update the state with the new value as you are accessing from state this will work

Comment: tab.icon can be use to show icon of particular tab but how to handle when user updates the icon. And i need to pass id of icon instead of name.

Answer (score 0):

initialize 'input box' with empty value from code behind.